# Prove that $T$ factors through $\pi$ if and only if $A\subset \ker(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces and $A$ a subspace of $V$. Suppose $T:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation and let $\pi:V\rightarrow V/A$ be the canonical projection map. Show that $T$ factors through $\pi$ if and only if $A\subset \ker(T)$.

I've got the forward implication. I am having trouble with the suppose $A\subset \ker(T)$ and coming up with a suitable factoring function. Essentially I need a mapping $f:V/A\rightarrow W$ such that $T=f\circ \pi$. I've tried messing around with basis but I just can't seem to work out how $A$ being in the kernel of T lets me do anything. The closest I've come up with is,
\begin{align*}
f([\vec{k}]_A)=
\begin{cases}
\vec{0}_W,&\text{ if }\vec{k}\in A\\
T(\vec{k}),&\text{ if }\vec{k}\notin A.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
But $f$ is not well defined on equivalence classes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Define $f: \frac VA\to W$ by $f(v+A)=T(v)$.

Suppose $v+A=u+A$. Then $u-v\in A\subseteq\ker T$. So $T(v)=T(u)$.